# Split string by array of strings

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string like "there are many apples in my fridge" or "the apples have been eaten", which I need to split based on an array of strings, such as { "apples", "bananas", "oranges", "grapefruit", "lemons"...}

Is there an out-of-box C# function that supports this, or do I need to build my own?

Comment: You might want to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Ha, too easy, thanks... I didnt realise it did exactly this (versus the usual splitting by single chars).